# How Django set path to files

Tags: django, file, path

In a django project, I want to open a file "file.png" (from images folder) in "worker.py".

- worker.py
- images
- - file.png
- - otherfile.png

It works well using the terminal, but when the server call this function I get this error:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: "images/file.png"

So my question is, where django set relative path?
Where should I put file.png to get it in worker.py using open() function?

Thanks

Comment: For the python scripts its normal system path, so your solution should be fine, did you check the rights of opening file.png?

Comment: no, that should be the problem...
Where does django allow access to this file?

Comment: It is not a django business, it is the operating system problem. You are writing the normal python script, that will be used than for the django framework, opening files and other operations are standard python operations. They don't aren't anyhow special in django python scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute path, in work.py you can define current path by

```
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_folder = os.path.join(current_path, images)
```

and then you can access the file with file name,

```
os.path.join(image_folder, xxxx.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. Add this in the `python.py` file to perform this task with files:

```
os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'File_Name.csv')
```